# mbstowcs() failing for special character

Tags: c++, linux, unicode

I'm using an xml that was generated by windows. it contains the copyright character. I have to take this file and parse it in my c++ linux application. I have to use the mbstowcs function but this function can't parse the copyright (R) char that looks: \302\256.

any suggestion?

10x!

Comment: Are you calling `setlocale()`? With what arguments? What is your `LANG` environment variable set to?

Comment: you have to set a locale which fits the encoding of the xml file

Answer (score 1):

What is the file's encoding? Was it written as a multibyte string or is it in UTF-8? UTF-8 isn't necessarily the same as a multibyte string so you might have to do the conversion yourself unless you're able to read UTF-8 (little bit tricky for C++ streams). I'm using an open source solution ([UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)) to do my conversions and it works fine on Linux and Windows. It allows you to use std::string and std::wstring to do all the conversion stuff (wide string to utf-8 and vice versa).

Comment: `0302 0256` is the UTF-8 encoding of the `(R)` character (in octal), so UTF-8 seems to be what the OP has.